# Insert Into Table from Excel via VB button to stored procedure with Variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures

I have a simple table `AMC_GW_TESTTABLE` with two columns, *name* nvarchar(20) and *phone* nvarchar(12).  I also have a simple stored procedure with two variables.

```sql
create procedure AMC_GW_TESTSP (@name nvarchar(20),
                                @phone nvarchar(12)) as
insert into AMC_GW_Testtable (name,phone)
values (@name, @Phone)
```

I have been able to get a button in Excel to create the command:

```
exec dbo.amc_gw_testsp 'fred' '620-555-1212'
```

But it does not execute it.  I copy this to my SSMS exactly like it and execute it and it works fine.  Any ideas?

VBA code

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim connStr As String
    Dim param As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim param2 As ADODB.Parameter

    connStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;" _
              & "Initial Catalog=am_app);Data Source=bcu-sql-01"

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = connStr
    conn.Open

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "AMC_GW_TESTSP"
        Set param = .CreateParameter("@name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "Christopher")
        .Parameters.Append param
        Set param2 = .CreateParameter("@phone", adVarChar, adParamInput, 12, "0123456789")
        .Parameters.Append param

      .Execute
    End With

    conn.Close
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: In order to help you, please post the vba code which is trying to call the stored procedure.

Comment: Please wrap the macro in [error handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/error-trapping) even [dbengine error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730414/determine-real-cause-of-odbc-failure-error-3146-with-ms-access) to get a precise message of the issue.

Comment: Ok i have it working now.  The only issue now is it does not pass the second parameter.              '    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "AMC_GW_TESTSP"
        Set param = .CreateParameter("@Name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, "C").Value)
        .Parameters.Append param
        Set param2 = .CreateParameter("@Phone", adVarChar, adParamInput, 12, Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, "D").Value)
        .Parameters.Append param2
      .Execute
    End With'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I did not scare you with a request for VBA Code

To give you an idea of what you should have:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim connStr As String
Dim param As ADODB.Parameter
Dim param2 As ADODB.Parameter

    connStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;" & _
    "Initial Catalog=dbname;Data Source=servername"

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.ConnectionString = connStr
    conn.Open

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = conn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "AMC_GW_TESTSP"
        Set param = .CreateParameter("@name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "Christopher")
        .Parameters.Append param
        Set param2 = .CreateParameter("@phone", adVarChar, adParamInput, 12, "0123456789")
        .Parameters.Append param

      .Execute
    End With
    conn.Close
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Things that you will have to change.  Firstly the connection string (connStr).  You will need to provide database name in place of dbname and server in place of servername.  Also this string is assuming that you are using Windows Authentication for your SQL Server.  If not you need to remove Integrated Security=SSPI; and in its place supply User ID=myUser;Password=myPassword;.
Next you will notice that the last parameter in the .CreateParameter function is a fixed string ("Christopher" and "0123456789").  In your case, they should be variables taken from cells in the spreadsheet.  Please, please make sure that these strings do not contain ";" before trying to Execute.

I hope this helps, but feel free to contact me, if anything is less than clear!

PS You will need to make sure under Tools References, that you have the highest version of Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library checked (mine is 6.1, but anything 2.0 or higher definitely works).

Comment: I have modified the code per your instructions, i believe.  I posted the code in the original question, as it will not let me copy into the comment.  I click the button and i do not get an error but it does not insert the christopher 0123456789 into the table either.

Comment: I am further into it now.  I get the error object is already in collection, Cannot append.  When debugging it takes me to the second parrameters.append

Comment: Sorry for all the updates.  Figured out the problem the second append param needed to be param2.  SO it now inserts into my table!  Thanks, on to changing the christopher to a cell.  I am sure there will be questions to come.  i am going to try using cell c4 and d4 respectively for the name and phone

Comment: Sorry I've been out all day.  Are you ok now?  If so, please mark the question as answered.  Otherwise, leave a comment and I'll look at it overnight - its 10pm here (I'm in Germany) and I am tired!

Comment: Thanks for asking!  Just got it all figured out.  Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: There should be a tick (check mark) next to my answer,  which is currently greyed out. If you mouse click it, it will change colour. It is more than a little irritating from SO to make it grey, sInce all new users assume that something which is grey is disabled. They often think you need reputation before it becomes available. Glad to know that you are fixed. Have a good day. Jonathan