# ODBC MYSQL connect - where to get odbc error msgs

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, error-handling, odbc

I'm tryng to find out when my odbc dsn-less connection fails due to invalid user/password, to provide that specific info to user. Right now I get a generic messsage  that connection failed, from my vba error handling code.

- I was able to just see that specific error in odbc trace log...

*DIAG [S1000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'pool-173-xxx-xxx*

..but how can i get at that error message in my error handling code?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

- vba connection code and error handle..

  ```
  Function TestLogin(uid As String, pwd As String) As Boolean

      On Error GoTo TestError

      Dim dbs          As DAO.Database
      Dim qdf          As DAO.QueryDef
      Dim strcon As String

      mysqlUser = uid

      strcon = "ODBC; Driver=MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver;" & _
      "SERVER={accrrrs.cpbo3r0tdggvwertg.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com};DATABASE=testdb;PORT=3306;" & _
       "UID=" & uid & "; PWD=" & pwd & ";COLUMN_SIZE_S32=1;DFLT_BIGINT_BIND_STR=1;OPTION=3"


      Set dbs = CurrentDb()
      Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")


       qdf.Connect = strcon

       qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

       qdf.sql = "SELECT 1 "
        qdf.Execute

       TestLogin = True
       DoCmd.Close
       DoCmd.OpenForm "Switchboard"

  exit_errorTrap:
       Exit Function

  TestError:
     Dim myerror As DAO.Error
     For Each myerror In DBEngine.Errors
        With myerror
            If .Number <> 3146 Then
                MsgBox .Description
            End If
        End With
    Next
    Resume exit_errorTrap

   End Function
  ```

Comment: Try raising DBEngine errors in your error handler. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24251587/1422451).

Comment: thanks @parfait - so i tried that, and now shows error "ODBC - Connection to MYSQL ODBC... failed."  but its  same message whether no network or bad creds.

Comment: Please show your code and attempt unless we take your word for it.

Comment: thx - just added above

Comment: I still just get a generic "odbc - xxxxx failed" message. In the odbc log however, it does indicate the more specific "access denied.."  error.  How can i access this error info from odbc?