# ODBC insert Failed - error 3146 while editing and updating the recordset

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, odbc

I connected the MS Access - Frontend with MySQL database using ODBC Connector.

There I have the `tblCustomer` and `tblPayments`. `tblCustomer` is linked with the `tblPayments` with the foreign key.

I had written the code to update the payment details of the respective customer.

For that, we have to update the existing recordset of the `tblCustomer` with the new payment entries.

Basically, Existing customers' payment information can be changed. In `tblCustomer` we have to Update the new payment details.

Suppose the old balance is $10. Now the person has paid the $10. So the current balance will be $0.
When I try to edit and update the new $0 balance to the `tblCustomer` it shows me

> ODBC - inserting failed.

```vb
On Error GoTo Proc_Err

' variable for return from msgbox
Dim intRetValue As Integer
If Me.PaymentAmount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a payment amount or cancel the transaction.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If
If Me.txtPaymentVoucher < 1 Or IsNull(Me.txtPaymentVoucher) Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a voucher number.", vbOKOnly
    Me.txtPaymentVoucher.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
If Me.TransactionType = "Debit" Then
    If Me.PaymentAmount > 0 Then
        Me.PaymentAmount = Me.PaymentAmount * -1
    End If
End If
If Me.PaymentReturnedIndicator Then
    If Me.PaymentAmount > 0 Then
        MsgBox "If this is a returned check enter a negative figure.", vbOKOnly
        Me.PaymentAmount.SetFocus
    End If
End If
If Me.PaymentCustomerID = 0 Then
    Me.PaymentCustomerID = glngPaymentCustomerID
End If
If gbolNewItem Then
    If Me.cboTransactionType = "Payment" Then
        Me.txtLastPayment = Date
    End If
End If
Me.txtCustomerBalance = (Me.txtCustomerBalance + mcurPayAmount - Me.PaymentAmount)
Me.txtPalletBalance = (Me.txtPalletBalance + mintPallets - Me.txtPallets)
  
Dim dbsEastern As DAO.Database
Dim rsCustomers As DAO.Recordset
Dim lngCustomerID As Long
Dim strCustomerID As String
Set dbs = CurrentDb()
Set rsCustomers = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblCustomers")

lngCustomerID = Me.PaymentCustomerID
strCustomerID = "CustomerID = " & lngCustomerID
rsCustomers.MoveFirst
rsCustomers.FindFirst strCustomerID
rsCustomers.Edit
rsCustomers!CustomerBalance = Me.txtCustomerBalance
rsCustomers!Pallets = Me.txtPalletBalance
rsCustomers!CustomerLastPaymentDate = Now()
rsCustomers.Update
rsCustomers.Close
Set rsCustomers = Nothing

FormSaveRecord Me
gbolNewItem = False
gbolNewRec = False
Me.cboPaymentSelect.Enabled = True
Me.cboPaymentSelect.SetFocus
Me.cboPaymentSelect.Requery
Me.fsubNavigation.Enabled = True
cmdNormalMode
Proc_Exit:
    Exit Sub
Proc_Err:
    gdatErrorDate = Now()
    gintErrorNumber = Err.Number
    gstrErrorDescription = Err.Description
    gstrErrorModule = Me.Name
    gstrErrorRoutine = "Sub cmdSaveRecord_Click"
    gbolReturn = ErrorHandler()                           ' Display the error message
    Resume Proc_Exit

End Sub
```

When `rsCustomers.Update` line executes then ODBC - insert failed error - 3146 occurs.

I checked that the error implies the datatype-Mismatch - code 13.
Then I changed the datatype of my table as well, but still not inserting the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Andre showed you to the correct use of the `FindFirst` function, I find it pointless to open the whole customers table and then search for a single customer, when you can filter the recordset at point of creation to return only the customer you need.

```
lngCustomerID = Me.PaymentCustomerID
Set rsCustomers = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblCustomers WHERE CustomerID =" & lngCustomerID, dbOpenDynaset)

If rsCustomers.EOF Then
    Debug.Print "Customer not found"
    GoTo Proc_Exit
End If

'safe to update customer at this point
With rsCustomers
    .Edit
    '....
    .Update
End With
```

You should then probably change `rsCustomers` to `rsCustomer` to make more sense.

Comment: You're right. :-) I didn't check the full code.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks, I have tried it. But still, the error doesn't resolve. The Error code is 13 - (Mismatch dataType). @Kostas K.

Comment: Step through the code and see the values you are supplying, apparently one of them is of incorrect data type.

Comment: Thanks, Kostas K. Has resolved the problem by changing the datatype. Actually, datatype in the access is DateTime and in MySQL it is the only date.

Answer (score 0):

1. After `rs.FindFirst` you **must** check with `If rs.NoMatch Then` if you actually found a record to edit.
2. Use this to find the underlying problem of error 3146 "ODBC-Call failed":
   [Determine real cause of ODBC failure (error 3146) with ms-access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730414/determine-real-cause-of-odbc-failure-error-3146-with-ms-access)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks, I have tried it. But still, the error doesn't resolve. The Error code is 13 - (Mismatch dataType). @Andre, If you require any other code or the datatype code, will provide you.  Thank you very much.