# ODBC--Call failed on RecordSet

Tags: database, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016, vba7, msdasql

Hellow i need your help i have a access database software, so i decided to migrate into sql server by sql migration assistant after that i tested my linked tabled to my access Graphical user, but fails some of code it seems doesn't applied in that are linked in sql server my code is

```
Dim Activity As Recordset

Set Activity = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("UserActivity")
        
        Activity.AddNew
        
        Activity!ActivityType = "Login To Afya DB"
        Activity!RefDocument = Me.Name
        Activity!Description = "User Has Seen Home_Page"
        Activity!UserName = Me.txtUserName.Value
        Activity!ActionedOn = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
         
Activity.Update
```

I have tryed to add dbSeeChanges

```
Set Activity = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("UserActivity", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
        
        Activity.AddNew
        
        Activity!ActivityType = "Login To Afya DB"
        Activity!RefDocument = Me.Name
        Activity!Description = "User Has Seen Home_Page"
        Activity!UserName = Me.txtUserName.Value
        Activity!ActionedOn = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
         
Activity.Update
```

But still give this [Massage i get wen am starting excuting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1S6j.png) and When i debug the problem is

```
Activity.Update
```

Comment: See here to get the root error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24251587/3820271

Comment: My guess would be the date column, try doing just `Activity!ActionedOn = Now()` (or `Date()` if you want no time part).

Comment: The date column works fine

Comment: I think may be there is a way to use RecordSet for SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always pass *true date* values to a date/time field; `Format` returns text.

Also, list the error information if any. So:

```
Set Activity = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("UserActivity", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
        
Activity.AddNew
      
    Activity!ActivityType = "Login To Afya DB"
    Activity!RefDocument = Me.Name
    Activity!Description = "User Has Seen Home_Page"
    Activity!UserName = Me.txtUserName.Value
    Activity!ActionedOn = Date
         
Activity.Update

' Print ODBC error.
Debug.Print Errors(0)
```